# OleDb Exception

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledb, oledbexception

For 5 hour searching i can't find my mistake. I get this exception. What is wrong?

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in MyDictionary.exe
>
> Additional information: Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.

My code:

```
public void Insert(Word word)
{
    string language=FindLanguage();
    try
    {
        command.CommandText ="INSERT INTO "+language+" ( Native , Foreign , Definition , AddingDate)  values ( '" + word.Native + "' , '" + word.Foreign + "' , '" + word.Definition + "' ,'" + word.AddingDate + "')";
            command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
            connection.Open();

            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (connection != null)
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any more information in the exception, or any inner exceptions? What does the generated SQL statement look like? Does it work if executed from the Access IDE?

Comment: Use parameters to avoid sql injection and formatting errors.  Also, try putting brackets around your language variable: `[" + language + "]` in case there is a space or conflicting character in there.

Comment: Compose the string into a variable, so you can debug output the command string...then assign it to the CommandText. I bet you're getting some kind of unexpected syntax in your composed statement.

Comment: In particular, if there is a single quote in any of your terms, that will cause invalid syntax. Your Definition column would be a could candidate for that happening. As suggested above, parameters make this problem go away.

Comment: @LarsTech nothing changed,i get same exception

Comment: Then try putting brackets around all your field names.  Maybe Native, Definition, or Foreign is a keyword, etc.

Comment: maybe offtopic: why are you making a table for each language?
please show the value of command.CommandText

Comment: What is the run-time value of Command.Text when the exception is thrown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use parameters in your insert statement.Also looks like you are missing `command.Connection = connection;`.
Note that your SQL is prone for [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

```
command.CommandText ="INSERT INTO "+language+"([Native],[Foreign],[Definition],[AddingDate]) VALUES (@Native,@Foreign,@Definition,@AddingDate)";

command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Native", word.Native);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Foreign",word.Foreign);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Definition",word.Definition);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AddingDate",word.AddingDate);

command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
command.Connection = connection;
connection.Open();

command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Put brackets [] around your columns ([Native], [Foreign], ...). You might be running afoul of reserved words (especially Foreign).

Comment: Just Worked ,Thanks

Comment: @RavilYahyayev Great,Please mark it as answer if it helped

Comment: @JohnPrideaux Thanks,Edited.

Answer (score 0):

In OleDb the correct syntax of the `INSERT INTO` statement involves usage of the `SELECT` clause even though you're *appending* static values. So you need to change your query like bellow example.

Further, don't construct `try...catch..finally` if you don't actually handle a raised exception. In the sake of disposal use `using() { }` block instead. So here it is:

```
public void Insert(Word word)
{
    string language=FindLanguage();

    using (var connection = new OleDbConnection("connection string goes here"))
    using (var command = new OleDbCommand...)
    {
        command.CommandText = @
            "INSERT INTO " + language + "(Native, Foreign, Definition, AddingDate)" +
            "SELECT '"
                + word.Native + "' AS Native, '" 
                + word.Foreign + "' AS Foreign, '" 
                + word.Definition + "' AS Definition, '"
                + word.AddingDate + "' AS AddingDate"
        ;

        connection.Open();

        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        connection.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I've used VALUES (as the OP is) instead of SELECT and never had an issue.

Comment: That's funny. I always get this error when use `VALUES`. OleDb just don't get it; SQL server is fine with `VALUES`.

Comment: Very strange. Good advice, btw, about the try/catch/throw.